# Can you run both maven1 and maven2 at the same time?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, maven-1

Is it possible to have both versions of maven running on the same computer?

From what I understand you have to setup environmental variables for both of them, so won't that conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I understand you have to setup environmental variables for both of them, so won't that conflict?

No, because they don't use the same environment variables (`MAVEN_HOME` and `M2_HOME`) and the executable have different names (`maven` and `mvn`). So no conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. Checkout http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-m1-m2.html